# Attributes not bubbling up with dynamic lightning components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a "container" component that handles all of the component creation/removals dynamically in my app.

If the attribute `sharedAttribute` exists on both the parent and child component then using it like this:

```
<c:childObject sharedAttribute="{!v.sharedAttribute}"/>
```

should reflect changes on the parent object if the attribute is set on the child object.

However, if I create the child object dynamically like this:

```
$A.createComponent(
                "c:childObject",
                {
                    "sharedAttribute" : cmp.get("v.sharedAttribute")
                },
                function(newCmp){
                    //do stuff
                }
});
```

Then changes arent reflected on the parent component when the child component is updated.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please share the full component code showing both parent and child components code

Comment: This is enough information to answer the question.  Create any variant of this and you will see the same results.  I appreciate the help but adding additional code would add to the confusion.

Comment: It's not enough info since I need to see how you append the child to the parent component and how you are debugging the parent attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more digging I found out `.getReference("v.sharedAttribute")` should be used instead of `.get("v.sharedAttribute")` when creating components dynamically.

Here is the updated code:

```
$A.createComponent(
            "c:childObject",
            {
                "sharedAttribute" : cmp.getReference("v.sharedAttribute")
            },
            function(newCmp){
                //do stuff
            }
});
```

Everything now works.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please mark it as accepted.So that it can help others in the community.

Comment: I will when stackexchange lets me. I am seeing the error `You can accept your own answer tomorrow`.